# SVN Repository went down and .svn folder missing from the working copy

Tags: svn, svn-repository

My SVN Repository(server down for few hours) went DOWN.

When the SVN Users update their working copies, '.svn' folder and files/folders that are synced to the repository went missing!

How to fix this issue? or Will this issue automatically resolved when the server is UP?

Thanks,
Pandiarajan K

Comment: How did the .svn file got missing? They are hidden files I hope you have checked that.

Comment: @subirkumarsao I was wrong '.svn' folder exists but other working copy contents are missing. Thanks for your reply. Regards, Pandiarajan

Answer (score 0):

As SVN was specifically designed to assure that one can work offline, there seem to be roughly three main possibilities:

1. You are using some custom-made scripts that screwed you up (this is not a pure conjecture - I've seen some questions asked here that in the end resolved exactly to this).
2. You are mistaken.
3. Someone sabotaged your system on purpose or by mistake (this *is* a pure conjecture).

*Update after seeing your last comment:* it makes (3) more likely - someone inadvertently deleted the contents on *HEAD*. This is not a huge problem as you can always revert those changes.